# Assigning todays date to a column depending on the input of another column in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns

I have a very simple library, and I want a column to be assigned today's date when for that record there is a specific input made in an adjacent column in sharepoint 2013.

I basically have 3 options that can be selected in column 1; A, B and C let's say and when A is selected, I want the date to be returned in an adjacent column, column 2, for that record. But if B or C are selected, I want the column 2 to remain blank.

Any ideas? Sorry it's basic.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use a calculated column to do this?

Go to your simple libbray add a calculated field column with a text output.

And do an If statement. Remember you can use [today] for todays date.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

Cheers

Truez

Answer (score 0):

Note that Calculated Columns are only updated on Item creation or Item update;

- It is a SharePoint urban myth you can use [Today] in Calculated Columns; several blogs out there mention a [Today] trick... apply it, wait 24 hours and you will notice Calculated Columns do **not** magically update every day.
- You **can** use [Today] in **VIEW Filters**
- So using **[Today]** or **Today()** in a Calculated Column is basically the same as using the **Modified** date

#### Your question

If items are updated and you want to know when, you can use

Column1: Choice with options: A, B, C

Column2: (Calculated)

```
=IF( [Column1] = A , Modified , "" )
```

For more indepth discussion of getting a correct Today in a Calculated Column see: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123157/calculated-column-that-updates-daily